# Preimage of soluble subgroup of projective general linear group under canonical projection is soluble

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, general-linear-group

Let $V$ be a vector space and $\textrm{GL}(V)$ the group of automorphisms on $V$.

Let $Z(V) \vartriangleleft \textrm{GL}(V)$ the normal subgroup of homotheties on $V$ (*i.e.* the centre of $\textrm{GL}(V)$).

Let $\pi: \textrm{GL}(V) \to \textrm{PGL}(V):=\textrm{GL}(V)/Z(V)$ be the canonical projection.

Let $H<\textrm{PGL}(V)$ be a finite subgroup.

I want to show that if $H$ is soluble(/solvable) then $\pi^{-1}(H)$ is soluble.

My attempt at a proof:

There exists a sequence of groups:

$$
\{\textrm{Id}\}=:H_0 \vartriangleleft H_1 \vartriangleleft ... \vartriangleleft H_{r-1} \vartriangleleft H_{r}:= H
$$
such that $H_{i}/H_{i-1}$ is Abelian for all $i \in \{ 1,...,r \}$.

If we then let $G_i:= \pi^{-1}(H_i)$ for all $i \in \{0,...,r \}$, then we have a sequence

$$
\{\textrm{Id}\}=:G_0 \vartriangleleft G_1 \vartriangleleft ... \vartriangleleft G_{r-1} \vartriangleleft G_{r}:= G
$$
as the holomorphic preimage of a normal subgroup is again normal.

My only difficulty lies in showing that $G_{i}/G_{i-1} = \pi^{-1}(H_i)/\pi^{-1}(H_{i-1})$ is Abelian for all $i \in \{ 1,...,r \}$.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how one would go about demonstrating this last bit / any counterexample?

This is related to my attempted proof of [this statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606259/image-of-subgroups-of-the-general-linear-group-under-the-canonical-projection?noredirect=1#comment7412790_3606259), which, as was pointed out in a comment, is in fact false.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: It follows immediately from the Third Isomorphism Theorem

Comment: @DerekHolt If it follows from such a general statement, then where does the proof go wrong when we take any group $G$, any normal subgroup $N \vartriangleleft G$, the projection $\pi: G \to G/N$, and a subgroup $H<G/N$?

Comment: What I mean is we could have $G$ insoluble, and $N = G$, so that $G/N$ is trivial, and $\pi^{-1}(H)=G$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks for pointing that out to me. I am afraid that the OP refers to it as Wagner's theorem because it appears in a textbook by [A. Wagner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascher_Wagner) (no relation, as far as I am aware).

Comment: Sure, I know. But it sounds so good, doesn't it?

Comment: The problem is that $G_0 := \pi^{-1}(H_0)$  is not the trivial subgroup, it is $Z(V)$. In this case, $Z(V)$ is abelian so the proof works. For a general normal subgroup $N$, the argument works if and only if $N$ is abelian, but it would extend easily to the case when $N$ is solvable.

Comment: @DerekHolt Brilliant, thanks!

Comment: @DietrichBurde Certainly. One of the many delights of having a relatively common surname.